# What is the invocation procedure for ifort in an intel oneAPI base installation?

Tags: intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am trying to use math kernel library of intel along with its fortran compiler, which comes built into the oneAPI basekit. However, the command "ifort" does not work since the terminal complains about it not being found in the system. I had setup the environment with the command "source intel/oneapi/setvars.sh" but that does not seem to help. Do you have any idea as to how to activate the compiler?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ifort command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461165/ifort-command-not-found)

Comment: Please do not open duplicate questions. Instead, try to provide more detsiled information for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Intel Math Kernal Library comes along with Intel Base Toolkit and you can  download a single component of Intel MKL. Please find these links for the installation of a [single component](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-download.html) and [full installation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html)

Intel Fortran will come from [Intel HPC Toolkit](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit-download.html). You can use the [Intel Link Line Advisor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html) for the exact compilation of your fortran code with MKL.

As fortran comes from HPC Toolkit, you need to have both to run the code

Comment: Please do not put the same answer under multiple questions. Instead, onxe you get sufficient reputation points, vote to close one of the questions as a duplicate. In this case, the other one should be the original, linked under the question. I suggest edit your other answer to include the links. Clearly, you just did a copy-paste of the answer but you should have done a copy paste of the answers' source.

Comment: In the end I closed the other one as a duplicate and upvoted this answer so that it is possible. But the other one was the true original with a solution already found in the comments. Having an actual answer is good, though. It would be great if answerers representing the Intel company (not only you) learned the common rules of this site because they may represent the company name in a worse way than intended.